# Which interesting and helpful YouTube channels do you recommend?

Tags: tutorials

For starting I liked https://www.youtube.com/user/14mech14/videos. Which channels do you recommend?

Comment: I can't recommend any yet, since all i have seen so far introduce faulty stuff for beginners, which isn't a good thing.

Comment: Personally, I DESPISE instructional videos.  Give me a good manual any day.